# Fail to create db with entity framework 7 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04

I'm following the following tutorial:

**http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/coreclr/getting-started-linux.html#create-your-database**

and I came across a problem with using entity framework to create a new database for my app. Running the command `dnx ef migrations add MyFirstMigration` throws me this error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'KeepItSolved, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
>       File name: 'KeepItSolved, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.RoslynCompilationException: /home/demo/kistest/src/KeepItSolved/Migrations/20160414215220_InitialMigration.cs(17,74):
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name
>   'SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy' does not exist in the current
>   context
>       /home/demo/kistest/src/KeepItSolved/Migrations/20160414215220_InitialMigration.cs(69,74):
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name
>   'SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy' does not exist in the current
>   context
>       /home/demo/kistest/src/KeepItSolved/Migrations/20160414215220_InitialMigration.cs(89,74):
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name
>   'SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy' does not exist in the current
>   context
>       /home/demo/kistest/src/KeepItSolved/Migrations/20160414215220_InitialMigration.Designer.cs(18,69):
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name
>   'SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy' does not exist in the current
>   context
>       /home/demo/kistest/src/KeepItSolved/Migrations/SolvedContextModelSnapshot.cs(17,69):
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name
>   'SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy' does not exist in the current
>   context
>       /home/demo/kistest/src/KeepItSolved/Models/SolvedContext.cs(29,19):
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not
>   contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and no extension method
>   'UseSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>       /home/demo/kistest/src/KeepItSolved/Startup.cs(71,18): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder'
>   does not contain a definition for 'AddSqlServer' and no extension
>   method 'AddSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type
>   'EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)
>          at Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.RoslynProjectReference.Load(AssemblyName
>   assemblyName, IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
>          at Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CompilationEngine.LoadProject(Project
>   project, FrameworkName targetFramework, String aspect,
>   IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
>          at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.ProjectAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName
>   assemblyName, IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
>          at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.ProjectAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName
>   assemblyName)
>          at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.LoaderContainer.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
>          at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.DefaultLoadContext.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName
>   assemblyName)
>          at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoaderCache.GetOrAdd(AssemblyName
>   name, Func2 factory)
>          at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
>          at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyName)
>          at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.StartupInvoker..ctor(String
>   startupAssemblyName, String environment)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DbContextOperations..ctor(ILoggerProvider
>   loggerProvider, String assemblyName, String startupAssemblyName,
>   String environment)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.MigrationsOperations..ctor(ILoggerProvider
>   loggerProvider, String assemblyName, String startupAssemblyName,
>   String environment, String projectDir, String rootNamespace)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<.ctor>b__4()
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0()
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.Execute(Action action)
>       Could not load file or assembly 'KeepItSolved, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. General Exception
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's definietely not able to find the type "SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy".  I would chalk that up to EF7 not being released yet, and maybe you found a bug.  Or maybe migrations aren't working all the way on Linux yet.  Afaik it's not even in Release Candidate yet is it?

I would find the official bug tracker for EF7 development and post about it there.

Comment: It looks like KeepItSolved is trying to load SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy and it can't find SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy there for cannot load KeepItSolved.

Comment: Maybe you did this on Windows in Visual Studio And referenced something that is not available in .Net Core 5 and thus isn't in DNXCore.